Does service manual for Renault Mégane Mk 3 include Generation?
I would like to get Renault Mégane Mk 3 Generation service manual, but I was not able to find it and since service manuals for Mk 3 are payed I wonder whether they include also a guidelines for Generation series? I have asked Renault and haven't received an answer.

Ask the seller of the manual what Generation(s) are covered by the service manual you are interested in.
If the manual is offered for sale online, the seller's listing should contain this information.

The seller doesnt want to tell me this without me giving them my personal information. The seller doesnt not contain such information.

Because the seller refuses to fully describe what information the manual contains, it is not completely described and you as buyer cannot assess if the manual will assist you. Result: take a chance and buy it (it might assist you or might now), or buy it elsewhere from someone else, or do without it. (If the seller is offering the manual through some online source, would the seller take the manual back if it doesn't help you and refund the purchase price?)
